# Screen self rotates on Juno

Tags: release-juno

On my HP Probook (non-touch screen) the display will randomly rotate. It does this on its own even when I'm not using it. Any suggestions on what it could be?

Comment: This worked for me on an HP laptop: https://askubuntu.com/a/1047331/4770

Comment: see https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/17011/16438
disabling the service worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the accelerometer that HP puts in their laptops. Disable it and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar why but some people say that there is some sensor which do that. I manage to fix it using this line in terminal:

```
sudo mv /lib/systemd/system/iio-sensor-proxy.service /lib/systemd/system/iio-sensor-proxy.service_disabled
```