# How to disable screen rotation on Juno

Tags: release-juno

I have elementary OS Juno installed on my laptop and it automatically rotates the screen to upside-down. then i have to go to display to fix this problem. but it doesn't stays normal. Sometimes later it goes to upside-down again which is frustrating. On gnome3 there is a rotation lock button but I cannot find rotation lock button on Juno.

I don't need the screen rotation, how can I disable it completely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me but I needed to apply at each start up:

```
$ sudo systemctl stop iio-sensor-proxy.service 
$ sudo systemctl disable iio-sensor-proxy.service
```

-- For persistance I needed this:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove iio-sensor-proxy
```

Answer (score 6):

I have juno running in an HP EliteBook 8460p with the screen rotation problem when I tilt the keyboard. To stop this, this worked for me:

```
sudo systemctl stop iio-sensor-proxy.service
```

Comment: Sweet and simple..!

Answer (score 3):

Juno on Hp 8510w with screen rotation problem. I have tried: 
sudo systemctl disable iio-sensor-proxy.service, but command did not remove script /lib/systemd/system/iio-sensor-proxy.service

To disable it at startup, file was renamed:

```
sudo mv /lib/systemd/system/iio-sensor-proxy.service /lib/systemd/system/iio-sensor-proxy.service_disabled
```

Answer (score 2):

there is a rotation lock in juno available under display in the system settings.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me

```
xrandr -o normal
```

Comment: Worked for me on Elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera

Answer (score 0):

Elementary doesn't have a screen orientation setting AFAIK, but you can try the following in the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.orientation active false
```

I kinda like screen rotation :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not working. My screen rotates like crazy. I can't do any work :(

Comment: See if this post can help you:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035209/how-to-turn-off-screen-rotation-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get remove iio-sensor-proxy` solved this annoyance for me, Thank you!

Comment: Your participation is much appreciated Let me inform you that we love informative answers with step by step guide. Please try to post detailed information so that it is simple enough for someone with zero technical knowledge to easily understand.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen orientation-lock true
```

Comment: hum, side effect... lock screen is upside down. 
There must be other way... I will keep trying.